# Electron USB Printer Connection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, printing, usb, electron

We have developed electron windows app using react js framework. I have used *thermal printer node library* to connect usb printer for print data.

I have tried using share printer in the printer properties and using the command **\System_name\Printer_sharename** and it's work perfectly in **windows 8**

But **window 7** it's not working. Any idea to connect usb printer via electron app using node js ?

Comment: Did you find any solution about this?

Comment: Yes. We found one library **node-thermal-printer** for get the installed printer list and communicate.